# socket.gaierror gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known - pika rabbitMQ

Tags: python, sockets, docker, rabbitmq, pika

I am trying to send a message from a python server hosted on localhost:5000 to a RabbitMQ server( using a docker image for RabbitMQ) , but I am getting the following error :

> socket.gaierror gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

I am running the docker image for RabbitMQ using the command where 'rabbithost' is the hostname I am using:

> sudo docker run -d --hostname rabbithost --name rabbitmq -p
>   15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 -p 5671:5671 rabbitmq:3-management

Here is the python code which is giving the error:

```
def send_to_queue(message):
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('guest', 'guest')
    parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('rabbithost', 5672, '/', credentials)
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='hello',body=message)
    connection.close()
    return "Message Sent!  "
```

The error is at line :

> connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)

mainly because of the parameters argument. 
I am not able to find the exact solution for this error.

Comment: Where is the python code running? On localhost? If yes then you either need to change `rabbithost` to `127.0.0.1` or make a host entry in `/etc/hosts` for `127.0.0.1 rabbithost`

Comment: @TarunLalwani This actually worked! . thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Where is the python code running? On localhost? If yes then you either need to change `rabbithost` to `127.0.0.1` or make a host entry in `/etc/hosts` for `127.0.0.1 rabbithost`